# jeditable: Getting an error when using Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables, jeditable

I have implemented a jquery Datatable with datatables.editable and Jeditable. I am able to use a text area as an editable field but I am having problems setting up a Select as the editable.

I have the following code to initialise the editable:

```
oTable.makeEditable({  
    sUpdateURL: "../ReconService.asmx/UpdateUser",  
    "aoColumns": [  
        null,  
        null,  
        {  
            indicator: 'Updating user...",  
            tooltip: "Change user",  
            type: "select",  
            submit: "Save",  
            data: getUserFilterOptions()  
        } 
    ]   
});
```

I then have a javascript / jquery function to get a list of users from the DB. Within the function I have tried a number of different things. The function as it stands now manually assembles the string to the format specified on the website [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

The function I have is as follows:

```
function getUserFilterOptions() { 
    $.ajax({  
        type:"POST",  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        url: "../ReconService.asmx/GetUsers",  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(result){  
            var userResult = result.d;  
            if (userResult.length > 0){  
                var text = "{'Select':'Select',";  
                $.each(userResult, function(index, val) {  
                    text += "'";  
                    text += val["value"];  
                    text += "':'";  
                    text += val["value"];  
                    text += "'";  
                    text += ",";  
                });  
                text += "'selected:'Select'}";  
                return text;  
            }  
        },  
    }); 
}
```

I have used the developer tools in Chrome to step through the function and the function returns the following string:
"{'Select':'Select','Administrator':'Administrator','User1':'User 1','selected':'Select'}"
The format is correct as far as i can tell but when I click on the editable table cell I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>   jquery.jeditable.mini.js:34   $.editable.types.select.content
>   jquery.jeditable.mini.js:34   $.fn.editable.each.reset.self.editing
>   jquery.jeditable.mini.js:18   jQuery.event.dispatch
>   jquery-1.8.3.js:3058   jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
>   jquery-1.8.3.js:2676

The confusing things is, if I copy that string value and put it directly into the data parameter of the jeditable it works fine. I have even created a function to just return this literal string and it works fine.

Example, replace the contents of the function as follows:

```
function getUserFilterOptions(){  
    return "{'Select':'Select','Administrator':'Administrator','User1':'User 1','selected':'Select'}"  
}
```

This works fine.

Im not an expert in javascript so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of ajax request from asynchronous to synchronous like this:

```
function getUserFilterOptions() { 
  return $.ajax({  
    type:"POST",  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    url: "/url",  
    dataType: "json",  
    async: false,
  }).responseText;
}
```

I tried to return your json from the server and it works.